# SSH to NetBSD 8.2 guest with X11 gives "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11-forwarding, netbsd

All,

I'm trying to set up SSH X11 forwarding from a NetBSD 8.2 VM (running via QEMU) to a Ubuntu 20.04 host. When I attempt to `ssh -X` into the machine, the `$DISPLAY` variable is not set and I get an error message: "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0". The following are pertinent environment details:

- `xauth` is installed on the NetBSD 8.2 VM and it works properly
- I have the line `ForwardX11 yes` in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file on both NetBSD as well as the Ubuntu host
- I have the line `XAuthLocation /usr/X711/bin/xauth` in the `ssh_config` file on NetBSD.

If I run `ssh -v`, then the relevant X11 output I get is the following:

```
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:10022).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

what could be possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X11 forwarding is disabled by default both in the `ssh` client and in the `sshd` server. The setting that controls it in the client is called `ForwardX11`, and the setting in the server is called `X11Forwarding`.

When connecting from the Ubuntu machine to the NetBSD machine using `ssh`, the following configuration files are being used:

- On the `ssh` client (Ubuntu machine)

  - `~/.ssh/config`
  - `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
- On the `sshd` server (NetBSD machine)

  - `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

With the [`ssh(1)`](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-8.2/ssh.1) client, however, you could just use the `-X` switch instead of editing any of the client configuration files. In fact, I would highly recommend using the `-X` switch over enabling X11 forwarding for all hosts (i.e. in a `Host *` block like I'm showing below).

If you do want to edit the `ssh` client configuration, the [`ssh_config(5)`](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-8.2/ssh_config.5) settings are the ones you already noted:

```
Host *
  ForwardX11 yes
  XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

The default for `XauthLocation` is already `/usr/bin/xauth` on Ubuntu, so there should be no need to specify it, unless you have another `xauth` program installed in another location and you want to use it with `ssh`.

The [`sshd(8)`](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-8.2/sshd.8) server on the NetBSD machine also has to allow X11 forwarding. These [`sshd_config(5)`](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-8.2/sshd_config.5) settings are the ones you still need to change:

```
X11Forwarding yes
XAuthLocation /usr/X11R6/bin/xauth
```

Again, the default for `XAuthLocation` is already `/usr/X11R6/bin/xauth` on NetBSD 8.2, so there should be no need to specify it.

After changing the `sshd_config` settings, you also need to restart the `sshd` service (as the **root** user):

```
service sshd restart
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm glad you got this in before this was closed.